# SumFromTo , A Recursive Function

Tags: haskell, recursion, sum, arguments

I am trying to do a recursive function that should give the sum of all integers between and including its two arguments. For example,
`sumFromTo 5 8` is `5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 26`. If the first argument is greater than the
second, the function should return 0.

This is what I got currently but I am a beginner and I don't think I did it right

```
sumFromTo :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumFromTo x y 
| x == 1 = 1 
| y == 1 = 1 
| x > 1 && y > 1 = x + y sumFromTo (x - 1)
| otherwise = 0
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to do this very simply:

```
sumFromTo :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumFromTo x y = sum [x..y]
```

However, I'm not sure what you'd want to do if x == y.

In the code you've given, your recursive definition isn't correct syntax. You've only given sumFromTo one argument, when it needs two, and you appear to have missed a + between the y and the function.

```
λ> sumFromTo 8 5
0
λ> sumFromTo 5 8
26
λ> sumFromTo 8 8
8
λ>
```

[a..b] means a list with a step of 1 between a and b, so [1..4] is [1,2,3,4]

Thanks to Phylogenesis, here is a recursive definition:

```
sumFromTo :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumFromTo x y
    | x > y = 0
    | x == y = x
    | otherwise = x + sumFromTo (x + 1) y
```

Comment: You don't need the guards; you can just write `sumFromTo x y = sum [x..y]`, since if `y < x` then `[x..y] = []`.

Comment: This isn't a recursive definition. You probably need to do something like `otherwise = x + sumFromTo (x + 1) y` and add a definition for `x == y = x`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis True, I just thought it might be nice for him to know there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: Recursive definition is available [here](https://www.ideone.com/t45jCc).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Do you want to post that as another answer, or shall I add it to mine?

Comment: Add it to yours. No point polluting this question with multiple answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you make the problem too complex if you want to implement this with recursion. Basically there are two cases:

1. one where the lower bound is greater than the upper bound, in which case the sum is zero; and
2. one where the lower bound is less than or equal to the upper bound.

The first case (1) can be expressed by writing:

```
sumFromTo x y | x > y = 0
```

In the second case, the result is the lower bound plus the sum of the lowerbound plus one to the upper bound, so:

```
              | otherwise = x + sumFromTo (x+1) y
```

and putting these together:

```
sumFromTo :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
sumFromTo x y | x > y = 0
              | otherwise = x + sumFromTo (x+1) y
```

Comment: @commuSoft Thanks for letting me know that there is an easier way but the question basically told me to use recursion so that's why.

Comment: @zpalmtree Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nasser: but this *is* a recursive way to solve the problem.

Comment: @commuSoft Oh sorry I read your answer the wrong way! thanks.